# Screen share with Windows Remote Desktop Services

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, remote-desktop, c++-cli

I need to create a WPF application that gives me the possibility to connect to other computers in the same network. I'm looking into Windows Remote Desktop Services, but it seems like it doesn't have a screen sharing feature, necessary for me since I don't want the remote machine user to be logged out of their session.

Is the only way to achieve this a VNC route? Or are there options in the Windows RDS to have only screen sharing without logging out the active user?

Comment: I am not an expert for this, but I guess there is a reason why usable screen sharing software are not just thin wrappers around Windows RDS - those are complex software products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the time I've been working this field, I've not seen anything that does what you're looking to do, without using either VNC or some type of HTTP setup over across a Domain. But apart from screen sharing in MS Teams (not sure if an Enterprise option is required) everything else that I've seen requires a secure connection, and the issuance of a SessionID token from the CSR to the End User.

Hope that helps!